# my toast messages are not being displayed

Tags: android

I have an issue where my notifications are not being displayed. I initially used a snackbar which worked, but suddenly stopped working. I thought the issue was with the snackbar class and switched to using toast instead but those do not show up as well. I have checked to make sure notifications are not turned off in my app.

```
public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 0;
    EditText email,password;
    Button login;
    String emailCred,passwordCred;
    TextView emailer,caller;
    static csBar cShowProgress = csBar.getInstance();
    String tag_login_req = "tag_login_req";
    static ArrayList<child> childModel;
    private static final String loggedInParentTracker = "loggedIn";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        emailer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailIcon);
        caller = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callIcon);


        emailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Email();
            }
        });

        caller.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(loginActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(loginActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                }
                else
                {
                    Call();
                }
            }
        });



        // Let's mark this ViewGroup as an icon container
        Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(getApplicationContext(),FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
        FontManager.markAsIconContainer(findViewById(R.id.icons_container),iconFont);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        final boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {



                emailCred = email.getText().toString();
                passwordCred = password.getText().toString();

                if(emailCred.isEmpty())
                {
                    email.setError("Enter your Email");
                }
                else if(passwordCred.isEmpty())
                {
                    password.setError("Enter your Password");
                }
                else if(!isConnected)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this,"Sorry,Please connect to a network",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cShowProgress.showProgress(loginActivity.this);
                    try{
                        makeRequest(emailCred,passwordCred);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this,"Error logging in,Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void makeRequest(final String user, final String cred)
    {
        //the url we are posting the request to
        String url = "http://mobile.map.education/api/login";

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(loggedInParentTracker, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //the post request function
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        csBar.hideProgress();
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");

                            JSONArray children = (JSONArray) jsonResponse.get("child");
                            JSONArray img = (JSONArray) jsonResponse.get("passport");

                            if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this,jsonResponse.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                            {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("loggedIn",emailCred);
                                editor.apply();

                                profileService(user);
                                ptaService();
                                newsService();

                                fromResponse(children,img);

                                Intent loader = new Intent(loginActivity.this,childSelect.class);
                                startActivity(loader);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                //this handles any errors the volley package gets
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ){
            //this is a method to set the parameters we are sending to be in the proper format
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                //the proper format of the login parameters is portal[parameter name goes here]
                params.put("portal[username]", user);
                params.put("portal[password]", cred);
                params.put("portal[From]","web");
                return params;
            }
        };

        //this is a retry policy that has been set to deal with timeout errors
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        try{
            queuer.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest, tag_login_req);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this,"Error logging in,Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you make a [mcve]? You don't need this many lines to test if a Toast works

Comment: you have several Toasts here? which exactly doesn't show up?

Comment: @mic4ael none of them show up. I have certified that the condition is being met for them to be displayed but they are not displayed